# using MID function on a login function in EXCEL

Tags: excel, function, binary, logic

im having problem using Mid function inside a logic function.

im trying to use the next logic function

```
=AND(A111,A116,NOT(A117))
```

while in A111,A116,A117 Cells i have MID function

```
=MID(E110,1,1)
=MID(E110,2,1)
=MID(E110,3,1)
```

I used the MID function to seperate the binary number '101' that located in E110 cell.

now, i dont know why but the Logic function returning an error and not making the calculation while im using 'MID', any idea what can cause this problem?

there is any alternative ways of doing it?
hope its clear, thanks alot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to pass a text as a value as when you extract using `MID` it will return a text type. You cannot then pass a logic operator on these results. Change your formulas on A111, A116, and A117 to:

```
=VALUE(MID(E110,1,1))
=VALUE(MID(E110,2,1))
=VALUE(MID(E110,3,1))
```

Then your logical operator will be able to interpret the numericals 0 and 1 as TRUE and FALSE. Regards,